# Share image and text through whatsapp

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp, shareactionprovider

I use the following code to share an image and text through WhatsApp. It only shares the image, not the text, however. I have searched all over the Internet, but haven't found a solution.

```
 String message = Fname + Mobileno + Homeno + Workmail + Homemail
                + Gtalk + Skype + Address + Company + Title + Website;
      Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
      Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://"
                + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/Talk&Share/Images/profpic.png");

      shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message); 
      shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Contact"); 
      if(uri != null){
       shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
       shareIntent.setType("image/plain");
      }else{
       shareIntent.setType("plain/text");
      }

         return shareIntent;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26198732/add-caption-to-image-on-new-whatsapp-ver-2-11-399-android/26772262#26772262

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whatsapp Support Image sharing along with text.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,title + "\n\nLink : " + link );
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(imageFilePath));
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image via:"));
```

This will share image and EXTRA_TEXT will consider as image caption.

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE
```

instead of:

```
Intent.ACTION_SEND
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible, as WhatsApp does not support messages with both pictures and text in them. A message may consist of a single image, text sequence, audio file, contact or video. You cannot have a combination of any of those.

Comment: Is there any way I can detect which app is the sharer when using share action provider? So that I can use different intents.

Comment: @BasimSherif Not that I am aware of

Comment: It was not supporting but now it's working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26198732/add-caption-to-image-on-new-whatsapp-ver-2-11-399-android/26772262#26772262

Answer (score -1):

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 i.setType("text/plain");
 i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
 i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Message body");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share dialog title"));
```