# add caption to image on new whatsapp ver 2.11.399 (android)

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp, caption

Friends,

On android "whatsapp messenger" version 2.11.399 (Sep 30, 2014) it is possible to **add a caption** (textual decription) to a shared image.

I share image via intent as follows:

```
Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/jpeg");
Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
//share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send."); // NOT WORKING
startActivity(share);
```

How can I add the text to the image caption?

Comment: Did you get any answer?

Comment: Any idea then please answer it..

Comment: I send their support team question couple of days ago but didn't get any answer yet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@robert I wass passing those parameters in older version and it just sending image but when I update my Whats app  version with 2.11.432 And now it's showing me both Image and text as caption. I was noticed that it was not showing in 2.11.399 or any older version. Just try to update your whats app and let me know is it works or not!!  Your code is right just send one extra text also

```
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,shareBody);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(yourFile));
```

Comment: Yes! it is working in whatsapp latest version. 
This probably was a problem with version 2.11.399.
Thanks for your attention! :)