# Intent.EXTRA_TITLE not working when im trying to send text and image to other apps like whatsapp

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyiVm.jpg)Intent.EXTRA_TITLE not working when I'm trying to send text and  image to other apps like WhatsApp

this is the code I'm trying to

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, Heading);
                sendIntent.setType("image/*");
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                        Uri.parse("file://" + sharefile));
                sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,"Hello"));
```

when I'm using EXTRA_TEXT it is working fine but for EXTRA_TITLE not working please help me

Comment: What should whatsapp do with a title?

Comment: I'm trying to add a title to my news app after image

Comment: Is that ment as answer to my question?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether it's clear or not but `Intent.EXTRA_TITLE` is not meant to send anything to the other app. Instead it gives the `activity chooser` a title. You could use something like "Which app do you want to open to send this image?".

A working example:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "EXTRA_TEXT");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Heading");
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Hello");
startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

Notice: In this case the title will always be "Heading" and not "Hello". If you are using `ACTION_SEND` this parameter is not used. From Intent.java:

```
 * @param title Optional title that will be displayed in the chooser,
 * only when the target action is not ACTION_SEND or ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.
```

There are more `EXTRAS` but I don't know if WhatsApp supports them:

```
* Optional standard extras, which may be interpreted by some recipients as
* appropriate, are: {@link #EXTRA_EMAIL}, {@link #EXTRA_CC},
* {@link #EXTRA_BCC}, {@link #EXTRA_SUBJECT}.
```

---

### Edit:

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26971952/962638) post WhatsApp accepts `Intent.EXTRA_STREAM` and `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` at the same time to show an image caption.

Comment: thank you sir for your replay.EXTRA_SUBJECT is working on gmail but not in Whatsapp...is there any way to share title and text along with image to the whatsapp